# meaning of the word "blog-tube"?

Tags: meaning

I have happened upon it in [BBC Learning English](https://youtu.be/yay1OUgMSlo). It is at 5 minute and 22 second. Here it goes:

> [Bill] She is cheating!
>
> [Will] So, you keep saying, but do you have any evidence?
>
> [Bill] I literally just filmed it on my phone.
>
> [Will] What are you doing! You could be **blog-tubing** the answer.

What is *blog-tubing*? I cannot find its definition on the internet.

Comment: I think it's just a humorous neologism.  People sometimes use terms like [interwebs](https://www.lifewire.com/what-does-interweb-really-mean-3482412), [blogosphere](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blogosphere), [intertubes](https://gizmodo.com/234832/5-things-to-do-when-the-intertubes-are-clogged), and even [interblag](https://xkcd.com/181/) to humorously refer to the internet, and Will is probably doing something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's essentially some type of humorous portmanteau of ["blogging"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/blog) and ["Youtubing"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/youtube). I'd take it to mean "sharing (something) on the internet", where it could be shared via a blog, Youtube, or some other way.

See also:

- [Relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/181/)
- Urban Dictionary entry for ["blogotubes"](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=blogotubes)

Comment: It could also be relevant that this video is professionally produced and might be deliberately avoiding using a registered trademark like "YouTube".